# Damaged photos after resizing partition with EaseUS PartitionMaster

Tags: windows-10, photos, easeus-partition-manager

When I was copying my photos from the sdcard to the PC, I run out of space on my partition. I used EaseUS Partition Master to resize my partition and add some space from the unassigned space on my disk. The whole process should last no more than 30-40 seconds, but it froze at 95% and after an hour nothing changed. I was forced to shut down the computer. After that, the partition was visible, but not accessible. I used EaseUS PM once again to check the disk. The program repaired the partition and I could get in. The problem is, about 20% of the files (which 99% of them are photos) are damaged. I can't open them. Their size is correct tho. I even checked that with Tenorshare and it saw the photos (seems like one file contains 3 versions of them, picture attached). But my question is: Is there any way to restore these photos with their original, not changed, names and with GPS coords in EXIF? These two things are very important to me.

[image]

Comment: The fact trying to resize the partition froze indicates the disk has some problems, data recovery is never guaranteed, your criteria might not match up to that reality.  How confident are you that the images were not already corrupted?

Comment: I copied them directly from my phone to the pc. I saw them right after I copied them and that was just before resizing them. They looked untouched.

Comment: Why not recopy them to the PC?